# "java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory" when run app(play framework ) on ec2 instance

Tags: playframework, amazon-ec2, playframework-2.0

when i "play run" my app on ec2 instance, and accessing from browser, it will send the exception as follows:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
>       at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:164) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
>       at sbt.SimpleProcessBuilder.run(ProcessImpl.scala:383) ~[na:na]
>       at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder.run(ProcessImpl.scala:137) ~[na:na]
>       at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder$$anonfun$runBuffered$1.apply(ProcessImpl.scala:168) ~[na:na]

i don't know if it is the limitation on memory of ec2 intance (612M), but why the wide space of memory  is needed when initializing a simple play app?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. 
Actually, first i try to compile and package a sing file, and then scp to ec2 instance, but it failed also. That's because "there is native a single-file format for play application".
Fortunately i find the relative answer, using 'play dist' to create a standalone version for play application (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ProductionDist).

Thanks all!